# spark thrift server does not clean shuffle files

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, shuffle, amazon-emr, spark-thriftserver

We are running SQL queries against Spark EMR cluster using Spark Thrift Server and we see that when a SQL query (translated to Spark job) is finished, it's shuffle files located under `/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache` are not cleaned. This causes `No space left on device` eventually after running several queries.

If we stop the Spark Thrift Server, the shuffle files are then cleaned. 
Is there any way to make the cleanup run not only after the application is stopped but after every job run? 
We tried setting the following parameters

```
yarn.nodemanager.localizer.cache.cleanup.interval-ms=6000
yarn.nodemanager.localizer.cache.target-size-mb=1000
```

but the files are still not cleaned.
Any idea why it happens and how can we avoid it?

Comment: Did you find a solution in the end?

Comment: Did you find a solution in the end?